# MASM неразрешенный внешний симво

Tags: ассемблер, компоновщик

Компилирую .asm файлы в .obj при помощи MASM компилятора. После линковщиком от visual studio линкую все .obj файлы и .lib в .exe файл, но получаю ошибку

```
link.exe ../objects/ok.obj ../objects/opengl.obj ../../libs/glfw3dll.lib ../../libs/OpenGL32.Lib /entry:main
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.38.32919.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

LINK : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ main.        
fatal error LNK1120: неразрешенных внешних элементов: 1
```

в файле ok.asm main есть (если поменять main на ___a то ошибка останется и также если убрать ok.obj или opengl.obj из строки):

```
include opengl.asm

.code
main PROC
    call init                   ; Инициализируем GLFW
    call createWindow           ; Создаём окно

    call drawLoop

    call finish                 ; Выходим из программы без ошибки если цикл завершился
main endp
```

Сам opengl.asm:

```
includelib "glfw3dll.lib"

extern glfwInit: PROC
extern glfwCreateWindow: PROC
extern glfwMakeContextCurrent: PROC
extern glfwWindowShouldClose: PROC
extern glfwPollEvents: PROC
extern glfwSwapBuffers: PROC
extern glfwDestroyWindow: PROC
extern glfwTerminate: PROC

extern glBegin: PROC
extern glVertex2i: PROC
extern glVertex2f: PROC
extern glColor4f: PROC
extern glEnd: PROC

extern glEnable: PROC
extern glDisable: PROC
extern glBlendFunc: PROC
extern glClearColor: PROC
extern glClear: PROC

end
```

Answer (score 0):

В команде компоновщика необязательно добавлять все .obj файлы в командную строку, уберите `end` с opengl.asm и оставьте только основной файл в команде компоновщика (ok.obj)